# Summarize multiple transactions that share a common value but also have unique row identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm currently working with a data set that has a large number of unique groups, and within each group there could be one to many unique rows, to describe the type of transaction applicable to that group.  There are a limited number of types of transactions, and each transaction has a(n):

- Amount
- Location
- Date

The data set would look something like this:

[image]

What I would like it to do is combine all groups into a single line, and have three columns for each type of transaction.  I am trying to get the end result to look like this:

[image]

The closest I have gotten is to try a number of joins, based on the claim number while looking for the unique key.  Unfortunately my results end up looking like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get each unique Group to have *only* one row in the results, with the three Types spread out, having three columns each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all with conditional aggregation:

```
select   grp,
         sum(case when type = 'S' then amount else null end) as type_s_amt,
         min(case when type = 'S' then location else null end) as type_s_loc,
         min(case when type = 'S' then date else null end) as type_s_dt,
         sum(case when type = 'O' then amount else null end) as type_o_amt,
         min(case when type = 'O' then location else null end) as type_o_loc,
         min(case when type = 'O' then date else null end) as type_o_dt,
         sum(case when type = 'F' then amount else null end) as type_f_amt,
         min(case when type = 'F' then location else null end) as type_f_loc,
         min(case when type = 'F' then date else null end) as type_f_dt
from     tbl
group by grp
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7fae/5/0

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thank you!  Now, to learn more about conditional aggregation...